# Out of Memory Exception in mvc 5?

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-grid, export-to-excel

I need to display 40,000 records, I got system out of memory exception in MVC 5. Sometimes 70,000 records loads correctly and sometimes not even 40,000 records load. I need to display all records and export these records to the MS-Excel.
I used kendo grid to display the records. 
I saw somewhere kendo grid doesn't load huge number of records.

Comment: you're getting the out of memory exception when?  when viewing on the page or when exporting?  or both?

Comment: You should look into using paging with your kendo grid http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/pager

Comment: 60,000 records loading correctly, but not exporting to excel. when I click export button, I got the error.

Comment: 40,000 records not loading , i got out of memory exception.

Answer (score 0):

From the Telerik [forum](http://www.telerik.com/forums/system-out-of-memory):

> When OpenAccess executes a query the actual retrieval of results is split into chunks. There is a fetch size that determines the number of records that are read from the database in a single pass. With a query that returns a lot of records this means that the fetch size is not exceeded and not all 40 000 records will be retrieved at one time in memory. Iterating over the result data you will get  several reads from the database until the iteration is over. However, when you iterate over the result set subsequent reads are accumulated when you keep references to the objects that are iterated. 
>   An out of memory exception may be caused when you operate with all the records from the grid. The way to avoid such an error would be to work with the data in chunks. For example, a paging for the grid and an option that exports data sequentially from all pages will achieve this. The goal is to try to reduce the objects kept in-memory at a time and let the garbage collection free unneeded memory. A LINQ query with Skip() and  Take() is ideal in such cases where having all the data in-memory is costly.

and from http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/functionality/exporting/overview

> We strongly recommend not to export large amounts of data since there is a chance to encounter an exception(Timeout or OutOfMemory) if more than one user tries to export the same data simultaneously. RadGrid is not suitable for such scenarios and therefore we suggest that you limit the number of columns and rows. Also it is important to note that the hierarchy and the nested controls have a considerable effect on the performance in this scenario.

What the above is basically saying, is to reduce your result set via paging and/or reducing the number of columns that are fetched from the db to show only what is actually needed.

Not really sure what else you could do.  You have too much data, and you're running out of memory.  Gotta reduce the data to reduce the memory used.

Comment: I tried normal html table and web grid I got same error.

Comment: I don't think you are understanding the advice being given, you need to reduce your data set as Kritner and myself have said.  You are not going to get an answer on how to accomplish something you shouldn't be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Please go for the paging.And try to export all 40000 records without loding on to page. Which clears you that load data takes time and goes to memory out of exception.

Comment: I tried paging but when I click second page i got an error.